# Custom UITableViewCell editing animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiviewanimation

I'm writing a custom UITableView with custom UITableViewCells. An unfortunate side effect of this, as many devs have found out, is that when the table starts editing, the content (UILabel in my case) isn't automatically moved. So, here's the code I've written to deal with it located in the UITableViewCell custom subclass:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if (animated) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        CGRect titleFrame = self.titleLabel.frame;

        if (editing) {
            [self.titleLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(15, titleFrame.origin.y, titleFrame.size.width, titleFrame.size.height)];
        } else {
            [self.titleLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(25, titleFrame.origin.y, titleFrame.size.width, titleFrame.size.height)];

        }
    }completion:nil];
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out the correct options to use as no combination I've tried has worked right.  Without `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` the UILabel shifts to the far left before beginning the animation, which is not desirable. And without `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` the UILabel performs the animation fine, but then has a small rubberband effect on the end.
Any ideas as to what's going on?
Thanks.

**EDIT**:
I've figured out whats happening! Not sure how to fix it, but now I now exactly what the question is!

Firstly, I had to uncheck 'use Autolayout' to get the cell to move automatically.

The labels initial x value is 25 when not editing. When editing, if the animation takes effect without moving the label myself, it moves to 25 points right of the left accessory item. The reason the first line there says 15:

```
    if (editing) {
            [self.titleLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(15 ...
```

is because that 25 point gap is pretty wide, and doesn't look right. So the animation, with the code in place, moves the label to the 25 mark, then back to the 15 mark, creating that rubber banding effect.

In trying to remedy this problem, I've tried all sorts of things like moving the `[super setEditing:...]` call below the code, always setting the animated argument of that call to NO... on and on and no luck.  The solution is to somehow make the label animate over a shorter distance than the x value, or (as I was originally attempting to do) create the animation locally to send it to a specific x value and have it stay there.

My instincts tell me that it's a problem with the chain reaction of `[setEditing ]` calls that happens with the `UITableView` where the animation of the contentView (possibly) is happening before my code block, thus moving the label over and then my code executes, moving it back.

Note: the behavior occurs whether or not the label is a subview of contentView.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't shown it in the question but it looks like you're adding your `titleLabel` directly to the cell.

Add your custom content to the cell's `contentView` instead, with appropriate resizing masks, and it will resize for you during the normal transition to editing mode with no need to override any methods. That's how it works with the standard label and image view. The content view is resized to allow the editing accessories to be shown, and the content view's subviews resize automatically.

Answer (score 0):

try following code

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

   [self beginUpdates];

    if (animated) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        CGRect titleFrame = self.titleLabel.frame;

        if (editing) {
            [self.titleLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(15, titleFrame.origin.y, titleFrame.size.width, titleFrame.size.height)];
        } else {
            [self.titleLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(25, titleFrame.origin.y, titleFrame.size.width, titleFrame.size.height)];

        }
    }completion:nil];

   [self endUpdates];

}
```

Comment: the code snippet is in the uitableviewcell custom subclass and so cannot call [self beginUpdates] or [self endUpdates]; however, those calls are made before and after the setEditing call to the tableview itself.